# weird encoding in ios executable file of an app

Tags: ios, objective-c, encoding, character-encoding

I'm trying to see how does  certain ios apps executable files look like, what i do is export the app files to my computer using iexplorer, i then took a look at the info.plist to see the executable files, after that i opened them with my notepad to use the UTF - 8 Encoding, but here how does things look like in both files-in the opening of both of the files i see english words that are expressing directories:

sample of file 1:

‹"Ò.(?!ÑNÓU£C°îXjøe”Ú5O•½°{^ÿÝŒEÌrôðæ$@[3,ÔÜ£æ»8I˜hGw!*aHÒQ•tœl²þ„™AÍçßÍæ†´³)è:cÌ7H5æß-eFç¯î&Ø\n,$Ë$y»¥ÁB^6ÙP; i(q,AÅ 
âðð·'©=Ÿa"v!PBÛÚ"¤¬‹Wj·;ËsÌŽÚâZüŠ–ÇüÉ;ÜA´sI«¸Üæ¿÷ ›‚‰.êøLž

sample of file 2:

ßêª§gö«húDªÝn¡±CÅÁ¹ â=Ø‰ˆ4|®b¡    JeW-É¯ðó¦xgýgeéÀXœH7ßJÉ" 3‡rÜ6ÒI_ ƒr cdÅá¸|íð¼l;Töl±”›MÛ˜±o/ôÇô#¬RS;Y¥!ÜzGò“vî©6ØR¡‚>Ì0m5
ŸzrPÐiDMÊ|Þ·9âëYß,pØƒ‹£x—.àN5îüÝrjœG]Æ·

ironically in the second file i can see a huge block of english words absolutely fine, but i dont get it why i don't see the whole file very good? i have also tried to open the files in an objective-c compiler after i have made them .m but that again was useless???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The executable files contain machine langage (binary) and cannot easily be read or understand by human. The word you still see in english are probably comments left by compiler that are not executed.

Trying to open those files in a compiler won't work because if the compiler role is to convert objective-c in machine langage, he's not able to convert the other way. For a same set of machine instructions, there are many ways to code it in objective-c.

The only way to get a source-code from a binary executable is to do some retro-engineering. It is done by converting the binary executable in assembly langage (it's a very low level langage but with understandable syntax) and then trying to reproduce the instructions with a higher-level langage such as objective-C.

Comment: but that dose not answer the question why in the second file i can see a whole block of english words absolutely fine? and is there anyway to convert this machine language to objective-c language- as we know they were either programmed in objective-c or in swift?

Comment: I edited my answer with some precisions I hope it helps you understand better